# Power BI Measure not updated upon row level filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following power bi measure:

IF(
[Current Rank] = [Previous Rank],
0,
IF(
[Current Rank] > [Previous Rank],
-1,
1
)
)

When I apply row level filtering, the measures [Current Rank], [Previous Rank] are updated, but this new measure is not, any ideas?

I expected that since the current rank is changing, the new measure values will change as well

Comment: Isn't this a calculated column and not a measure? Calculated columns are computed once, when the model is loaded.

Comment: Please provide context and sample data that would allow to understand and replicate the problem.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Yes, the problem was that it was a calculated column and not a measure, I thought it was a measure. I found no way to tell the difference except a small icon next to the name of the column. This question is solved.